# How to remote debug python code in a Docker Container with VS Code

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I've just registered for this question. It's about if it's possible to remote debug python code in a Docker Container with VS Code.
I am having a completely configured Docker Container here. I got a little bit of help with it, and I'm pretty new to docker anyways. In it runs Odoo v10. But I cant get the remote debug in VS Code to work. I have tried [this](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Debugging:-Remote-Debuging) explanation, but I don't really get it. 
Is it even possible? And if yes, how can I get it to work?
I'm running Kubuntu 16.04 with VS Code 1.6.1 and the Python Extension from Don Jayamanne.
Ah yeah and I hope I am at the right location with this question and it's not against any rules.

**UPDATE:**

Just tried the way of Elton Stoneman. With it I'm getting this error:

```
There was an error in starting the debug server. 
Error = {"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect",
         "address":"172.21.0.4","port":3000}
```

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM **cut_out**
USER root
# debug/dev settings

RUN pip install \
        watchdog

COPY workspace/pysrc /pysrc
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        python-dev \
 && /usr/bin/python /pysrc/setup_cython.py build_ext --inplace \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 3000

USER odoo
```

The `pysrc` in my Dockerfile is there because this was intended for working with PyDev (Eclipse) before.

This is the `run command` I've used:

```
docker-compose run -d -p 3000:3000 odoo
```

And this is the important part of my `launch.json`:

```
    {
        "name": "Attach (Remote Debug)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "remoteRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "port": 3000,
        "secret": "my_secret",
        "host": "172.21.0.4"
    }
```

I hope that's enough information for now.

**UPDATE 2:**

Alright I found the solution. I totally misunderstood how Docker works and tried it completeley wrong. I already had a completeley configured Docker-compose. So everything I needed to do was to adapt my VS Code configs to the docker-compose.yml. This means that I just had to change the launch.json to the port 8069 (default Odoo port) and just need to use `docker-compose up`, then the debugging works in VS Code. 
Unfortunately the use of `ptvsd` kinda destroys my Odoo environment, but at least I'm able to debug now. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your Update 2 with what you put in your `launch.json`? Also not sure what you meant when you said you're using `docker-compose up`. An explanation of your workflow would be appreciated :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have my `launch.json` for this project anymore, but all I changed in it was the port to `"port": 8069`.
`docker-compose` is a tool that extends the functionality of docker. `docker-compose up` just starts all the found docker containers.
I have to say that it still didn't work as intended, I never got remote debugging docker in VS Code to work tbh. If you get it to work please tell me :).

Comment: Hi - follow up question - why did changing the port to 8069 solve your issue? Do you have the original docker-compose file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is possible - when the Python app is running in a Docker container, you can treat it like a remote machine.

In your Docker image, you'll need to make the remote debugging port available (e.g. `EXPOSE 3000` in the Dockerfile), include the `ptvsd` setup in your Python app, and then publish the port when you run the container, something like:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 my-image
```

Then use `docker inspect` to get the IP address of the running container, and that's what you use for the `host` in the launch file.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot already! But one more thing: Do I have to import `ptvsd` in every `.py` script I am having? Because that would be a lot with Odoo. Is there a better way, like for example one import per project?

Comment: Just had time to try it your way, unfortunately it's not working. Everytime I try to debug I get this error in my debug console:

Comment: Sorry, just getting used to StackOverflow. This Error:
`There was an error in starting the debug server. Error = {"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"172.21.0.4","port":3000}
There was an error in starting the debug server. Error = {"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"172.21.0.4","port":3000}`
(I get the same output twice)
Any Ideas maybe?

Comment: Can you update your question with your Dockerfile and `docker run` command?

Comment: `EXPOSE` doesn't actually expose the port (but `-p` does), so you can always leave that out if you don't feel like keeping it around for documentation purposes; https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Answer (score 3):

works with **vscode 1.45.0** & later. for reference files https://gist.github.com/kerbrose/e646aaf9daece42b46091e2ca0eb55d0

1- Edit your `docker.dev` file & insert `RUN pip3 install -U debugpy`. this will install a python package `debugpy` instead of the deprecated one `ptvsd` because your vscode (local) will be communicating to `debugpy` (remote) server of your docker image using it.

2- Start your containers. however you will be starting the python package that you just installed `debugpy`. it could be as next command from your shell.

```sh
docker-compose run --rm -p 8888:3001 -p 8879:8069 {DOCKER IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST]} /usr/bin/python3 -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:3001 /usr/bin/odoo --db_user=odoo --db_host=db --db_password=odoo
```

3- Prepare your launcher file as following. please note that `port` will be related to odoo server. `debugServer` will be the port for the debug server

```json
{
    "name": "Odoo: Attach",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 8879,
    "debugServer": 8888,
    "host": "localhost",
    "pathMappings": [
        {
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/mnt/extra-addons",
        }
    ],
    "logToFile": true
}
```

Comment: yes, this is still working. do you face any problem??

Comment: I'm using this to start my docker (zope based application) `sudo docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v ... /usr/bin/python3 -m debugpy` I got `/usr/bin/python3: No module named debugpy` under Ubuntu

Comment: well, you just need to install debugpy module in your container. you could do it in multiple ways. if you run a public image. you log into such image using `docker exec -it -u 0 /bin/bash` then `pip3 install debugpy`. however if you have a docker file you could just add `RUN pip3 install -U debugpy` then rebuild the image.

Comment: https://dev.to/kerbrose/how-to-remote-debugging-odoo-docker-images-python-based-framework-4o2h

Answer (score 2):

If you want a nice step by step walkthrough of how to attach a remote debugger for VS code in a container you could check out the youtube video ["Debugging Python in Docker using VSCode"](https://youtu.be/b78Tg-YmJZI).

He also talks about how to configure the Docker file such that the container does not includes the debugger when run in production mode.