# Debug Pytest in docker container using VS Code

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, pytest, vscode-debugger

I have troubles to setup debugging of py.test code in docker container using VS Code.

After studying this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging
And this: [How to remote debug python code in a Docker Container with VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233928/how-to-remote-debug-python-code-in-a-docker-container-with-vs-code)

I have setup following debug configuration in vscode:

```
{
  "name": "Python: Attach",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "attach",
  "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "remoteRoot": "/capi",
  "port": 3000,
  "secret": "secret_text",
  "host": "localhost"
}
```

I have imported this bit into my test file:

```
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach("secret_text", address = ('0.0.0.0', 3000))
ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
```

And I made sure I open that 3000 port in docker-compose file:

```
 ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

I double checked that the port is open:

```
nmap -p 3000 localhost

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-07-19 10:53 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000074s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
3000/tcp open  ppp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.11 seconds
```

It seems to be the case. When I run pytest file from the container it starts and waits for debugger to be connected:

```
===================================================== test session starts =====================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.15, pytest-3.5.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /capi, inifile:
plugins: requests-mock-1.5.0, xdist-1.14, metadata-1.7.0, html-1.16.1, cov-2.5.1
collecting 0 items
```

But when I run this configuration from VS Code nothing seems to happen.

[image]
It seems to hang. Nothing in the debug console or in the docker container.

I have setup remote debug for a simple hello-world.py console app just for testing and it seems to work. So my assumption is it has something to do with the fact that I'm trying to debug a pytest.

Have anyone managed to do this? I would appreciate some help.

Comment: were you ever able to make any progress on this task?

Comment: nope, I just ran them in local env in the end :(

Comment: even, i am facing a lot of trouble doing this, i tired both in pycharm and vscode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and your post almost solves the problem.
When I tried implementing your solution I encountered the following issue:

```py
ImportError while loading conftest '/app/tests/conftest.py'.
     tests/conftest.py:36: in <module>
ptvsd.enable_attach("secret_text", address=("0.0.0.0", 5678))
E   TypeError: enable_attach() got multiple values for argument 'address'
```

Removing the "secret_text" value allowed me to hit the `wait_for_attach()` point and successfully attach the debugger to the code. I was able to hit breakpoints in my tests. Thank you!

**.vscode/launch.json**

```
{
  "name": "Python: Attach",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "attach",
  "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/code",
  "remoteRoot": "/app",
  "port": 5678,
  "host": "localhost"
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
ports:
 - "5678:5678"
```

**conftest.py**

```py
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach(address=("0.0.0.0", 5678))
ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
```

***Note**: The ptvsd lines are placed after all the imports.*

CLI command to execute tests:

```py
import subprocess
import click

@click.command()
def cli():
    return subprocess.call("pytest test", shell=True)
```

Sequence to debug tests:

1. `docker-compose up` (get container running)
2. `docker-compose exec MODULE CONTAINER_NAME FUNCTION_THAT_EXECUTES_TEST`
3. Attach debugger in VSCode

Tests will execute and hit whatever breakpoint you have setup.

Comment: Where are you placing the `CLI command to execute tests`?

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't connect neither, even following https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/3946. What worked for me was after following [@therightstuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72274986/1200914) answer, which I think it needs better explanation.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to VS code extensions and **install Dev Containers** from Microsoft.
2. In your VS code window, **in the left-bottom corner** there's the **button** **><** in blue. **Click it!** (or green if you are connected to a remote host) (in this image the [image: Button] is purple).
3. This will open a contextual menu on top of VS Code. After installing the previous extension now you can click "**Attach to Running Container**". Click there.
4. VS Code will open a new window that is running within your docker. Now in this window you must **install Python extension from Microsoft** to enable debugging.
5. Go to debug panel in this window and **add a new configuration for Python**. Add the following:

   ```
    {
     "configurations": [
      {
      "name": "Python: Pytest",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "module": "pytest",
      "args": [
        "$file"
      ],
      },
    ]
   }
   ```
6. Now open the file you want to test, and **click on the green triangle in the debug configuration with the name "Python: Pytest"**, which is the config you just added. If instead of running a unique file you want to run all tests or run a single test, in the previous config file put "your pytest arguments" instead of "$file" inside "args" option.

Comment: I had an issue with that configuration. It was not working for me unless I added `"version": "0.2.0",` before `"configurations":`

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question before discovering that Visual Studio Code has had built-in-support for remote debugging docker containers since 2019!

- [A quick guide I wrote to getting started](https://therightstuff.medium.com/how-to-attach-visual-studio-code-to-a-running-docker-container-3ff3f99d3856)
- [The official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers)